# What is the best way to record from a single fixed camera?

Tags: video, recording, production

I run a video system at my church that consists of two fixed robotic cameras among other things. The person who installed this equipment didn't have experience with video production, only display, so instead of a video mixer we have video input switchers, needless to say that doesn't work well for recording. The end result is that currently I'm only recording from a single camera.

An example of my work is here: http://www.mbcdet.com/media/. I'll disclose this is a Christian sermon so if you don't agree with what is said in the video I understand but I would appreciate if the feedback is *pertinent to the question*, thanks.

I know that ultimately recording from the second camera at the same time and mixing the inputs is a good way to go, or purchasing a video mixer and mixing the video inputs real time is also a good way to go. What I'm looking for is an answer on recording the video from a fixed camera in a way that doesn't seem *boring*, so to speak.

Comment: We actually get quite a few questions from church A/V tech's here.  I personally am one of the main A/V tech's at my church and also do A/V production work with a couple of Christian youth conferences in my area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a good answer to that.  There isn't a whole lot you can do with a fixed shot and making adjustments on a live shot is always a danger of being distracting, even when controlling it by hand as an experienced operator.  Making adjustments via a Pan Tilt Unit while the camera is live is going to be anything but smooth and will be very distracting.

I'd recommend either recording from both to edit in post or picking up one of the Black Magic Studio ATEM's (under $1000 HD video switcher with built in H264 encoding).

Comment: You're preaching to the choir :-) I've never come across the ATEM, it's been a few years since I've looked for new hardware.

Comment: Yeah, I generally pimp it for small organizations because it is so extremely cheap compared to anything else out there.  It does require a computer, but most churches in particular (and other non-profits) are already using a computer for non-linear editing, so they normally have the hardware available to make it work.  The next cheapest switcher I know of is over $1000 for a cheap SD switcher.